# can not get the values of fileupload control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get the value of file upload control but I get null after press the button I used following code

```
        string ImageName = string.Empty;            
        if (ImageUploadToDB.PostedFile != null && ImageUploadToDB.PostedFile.FileName!"")
        {
            ImageName = Path.GetFileName(ImageUploadToDB.FileName);
        }
```

I am getting the answer on previous post.

Comment: Are you using Update panel ?

Comment: Show you HTML code as well so that we can help you in right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
if (ImageUploadToDB.HasFile)
{
    string name = ImageUploadToDB.PostedFile.FileName;
}
```

Hope it helps you.
Thanks.

Comment: It does not go inside If block

Comment: It should go inside if loop. Post your file upload control html. there must be some problem.

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageUploadToDB" runat="server" Width="23%" /> <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="44px" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/images.jpg" Width="123px" 
                    onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />

Comment: I tried same, but working perfectly from my side. Have you put break point and check on your imagebutton click event? There you can find your problem.

Comment: Good. But what was a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
        if (ImageUploadToDB.PostedFile != null && ImageUploadToDB.PostedFile.FileName!"")
    {
        ImageName = Path.GetFileName(ImageUploadToDB.PostedFile.FileName);
    }
```

This shall work.

Comment: it does not go inside if block

Comment: Replace your if condition with if(ImageUploadToDB.HasFile). Then it will go inside the if loop.

Comment: Check your form_load event. I hope you are not binding the control again in the form load event.

Comment: May be edit your question and post your entire code-behind file for quick answer.